# сделать докер контейнер для подключения к серверному сокету

Tags: python, сокет, docker

Необходимо сделать докер контейнер для подключения к серверному сокету.
Но сокет не выдаёт сообщения о подключённом порте и, я думаю, что он просто не запустился на прослушивание

Содержимое файла Dockerfile:

```
FROM python
WORKDIR /home/apps/db/
COPY ./db-socket.py /db/
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["python", "/db/db-socket.py"]
```

Сокет на python:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print(addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    data.decode()
    if not data:
        break
conn.send(data.upper())
```

Клиентский python файл для подключения (запускаю в редакторе кода):

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(("localhost", 9090))
sock.send("stroka".encode())

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)

conn.close()
```

Ответ клиента:

```
File "C:\Repos\paint\tasks.py", line 137, in <module>
    sock.connect(("localhost", 9090))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]
```

Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Comment: А контейнер вы как запускаете ?

Comment: docker container run test

Comment: Клиентский код подключается к localhost, при данном запуске контейнера у вас нет открытого порта на localhost, вам нужно "прокидывать порт". 
Я вам специально не скажу как - тут все напиано. вы все поймете https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: > Я вам специально не скажу как - а я скажу, просто для проверки: docker container run -p 9090:9090 test

Comment: Спасибо Вам за совет! Я пробовала так, не получилось. Еще пробовала 9090:00, тоже не получилось :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас проблема не с докером, а кодом, как указали в комментария, что вам нужно добавлять `-p 9090:9090`, но даже в этом случае код не будет работать.

```py
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    data.decode()
    if not data:
        break
conn.send(data.upper())
```

Тут вы в бесконечном цикле читаете данные. Т.е. у вас стартует сервер и ожидает от клиента сообщение, вам приходит "stroka", т.к. это не пустой массив, то из цикла не выходит и идет на следующую итерацию, где опять пытается читать.

Тогда как в клиенте, вы отправляете "stroka" и ждете ответа от сервера, который никогда не появится, т.к. у вас сервер тоже ждет.

Так у вас и получается, что они ждут друг друга.

Если написать что-то такое в сервере:

```py
while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print(addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.send(data.upper())
    conn.close()
```

То ваш клиент вернет ответ (`STROKA`), даже в докере, только запускайте его с `-p 9090:9090`.

Comment: Exploding Kitten - круто, спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте флаг `--network="host"` в запуск контейнера.
То-есть: `docker run -p 9090:9090 -itd --network="host"`

И все ваши проблемы решаться, а локальные порты контейнера пробросятся на локалку машины.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!